# Align edge loops with different scale

Tags: modeling, workflow, edges, topology

What would be the quickest way to align multiple edge loops that are scaled differently to one that is scaled correctly?

Let's say I want to shape all the edge loops of the first example like the top one, so that they form a cylinder.

[image]

Comment: Consider changing accepted answer for the one provided by @Denis. It's simple and faster.

Comment: @LukeD Thanks -__- And if you don't already have LoopTools installed, then my way IS faster.

Comment: @ShadyPuck are you doing this for points or for qood quality help? As it is in a question, this is an example and in this case maybe it is faster to do it manually (or not, 4-5 clicks to activate LoopTools? One time thing.), but what if beside example he wants to streighten 20 or more loop cuts?

Comment: @LukeD The OP accepted my answer, so clearly it was good quality, or at least what they needed.

Comment: @ShadyPuck I was making the same answer as yours (you were faster) because this was only way I knew. Then I saw LoopTools version and it is just a better way for this task so I propose changing accepted answer for future visitors or for people as myself. End of topic.

Comment: Both answers helped me and I think they complement quite well. If I understood correctly, If you want to use loop tools to align all the edges and form a perfect cylinder, the top and the bottom loops have to have the same size. In the example I provided this was the case, but if it wasn't, before using loop tools you would have to scale them using the snap scale method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select the first edge loop that you want to adjust. Set the *Snapping* type to *Closest Vertex*:

[image]

Key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then hover over one of the vertices in the top loop, then <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>.

Repeat for each loop.

*Procedure:*

[image]

Comment: To whomever down voted my answer, can they tell me why so that I can improve it?

Answer (score 8):

That can be done very quickly with **Loop Tools** addon that can be found and enabled in the user preferences.

In edit mode select top and bottom loops and in tools panel look for **Loop Tools** section, select **Curve** and all the intermediary loops will be aligned automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Loop Tools Curve**

[image]

[image]

In the images above. Left side original mesh. Middle Edit Mode with Loop Tools. Right side result. Loop tools are on the left side with settings.  In this example we choose loops of different sizes to illustrate generality.  Only two loops need be selected.